# Why does zero padding an image using np.hstack make it white when displayed using imshow?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, matplotlib, image-processing

I have an image `patch` of size: `(200, 350 , 3)`

**patch**:

[image]

I'm trying to horizontally stack a black image to this using:

```
stacked_image = np.hstack((patch, np.zeros((200, 2450, 3))))
```

So the shape of stacked_image is: `(200, 2800, 3)`

But the image patch is whitened when I display it with `plt.imshow()` or `cv2.imshow()`
[image]

I don't understand why the patch is whitened. I was expecting the patch image and the remaining column pixels to be black. How can I achieve this?

Also, when I save the image using `cv2.imwrite`, I get the expected output:

```
cv2.imwrite(r'hstack.png', np.hstack((patch, np.zeros((200, 2450, 3)))))
```

[image]

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: According to the imshow() docs, `X` may be a float array, a uint8 array or a PIL image. Would it be possible that the `dtype` of your patch is different from np.zeros(), which is `float64`?

Comment: The uint8 seems to work, but the float64 dtype doesn't. I don't understand why.

Comment: @ChunKitYeung I just checked the dtype of patch and it is `uint8` which is different from the np.zeros(float64). Probably this was the problem

Comment: I noticed that when both are float 64, it doesn't work but when both are uint8 it does! Hopefully someone can explain why this is the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe your issue is the `dtype`
change

```
np.zeros((200, 2450, 3))
```

to

```
np.zeros((200, 2450, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
```

you can also try to look at the [cmap](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) parameter of pyplot.imshow

Comment: Yes, thank you so much!! This works! Can you explain why the dtype was important?

Comment: The default dtype for `np.zeros` is float(64-bit) your color range for each channel is 8-bit(256), that's why there was a mismatch. This is a common gotchya when working with images